# Pairing variables from 2 arrays for use in an equation

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to pull 2 separate variable from 2 arrays and have python solve a set of equations using both variables.  I need to use the variables in pairs only, the arrays are already in the correct order so I feel like I just need to enumerate the variables so python only uses each variable once instead of what it is currently doing which is computing every possible combination of the variables.

`pa` is Phase Angle in radians, such as: 1.20729, 1.20616.

`distance` is in meters, such as: 34753800.126, 21632361.184.

`A` = Area and is set to 1

`Ref` is Reflectivity and is set to 0.175

The result should be the apparent magnitude of each pair of variables, such as:

- 13.6148934 (uses 1.20729 and 34753800.126)
- 12.584035  ( uses 1.20616 and 21632361.184)

I don't want a result that uses 1.20729 and 21632361.184

```
with open('ApparentMagnitude.txt', 'w') as output:
    for pa in PA_Rads_Array:
        for distance in Meters_Array:
            P = (1/pi) * (np.sin(pa) + ((pi - pa) * np.cos(pa)))
            RAP = Ref * A * P
            RAPd = RAP/(distance**2)
            M = -26.7 - (2.5 * np.log10(RAPd))
            output.write(str(M) + "\n")
```

Comment: Before an overeager mod down-votes your post, format your code, include examples of what your input is like and what you expect as an output.  :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

> Given two lists, say `l1 = [1,2,3]` and `l2 = [4,5,6]`, `zip(l1, l2)`
> returns `(1, 4)`, `(2, 5)` and `(3, 6)`.

Then:

```
with open('ApparentMagnitude.txt', 'w') as output:
    for pa,distance in zip(PA_Rads_Array, Meters_Array):
        P = (1/pi) * (np.sin(pa) + ((pi - pa) * np.cos(pa)))
        RAP = Ref * A * P
        RAPd = RAP/(distance**2)
        M = -26.7 - (2.5 * np.log10(RAPd))
        output.write(str(M) + "\n")
```